# express.js: how to download stream as a file?

Tags: node.js, express

My story is as follows: a user uploads a txt file to an express.js server, where the text file is transformed to a pdf file; the pdf file can be streamed back to the browser via request.pipe. I can get the stream on the user side, but how to let the browser *download* the stream as a pdf file?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you already have the pdf as a readable stream, you can just do something like:

```
res.attachment('pdfname.pdf');
pdfstream.pipe(res);
```

Or if you have the pdf on disk, you can send it to the client simply with:

```
res.download('/path/to/file.pdf');
```

Or specify a custom filename that's presented to the browser:

```
res.download('/path/to/file.pdf', 'pdfname.pdf');
```